# Splitting PDF into evenly sized files

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Problem: I wrote a script that should be splitting a PDF into chunks of 5 pages. What I get is a series of PDFs, each with a name that suggests that the split has occurred properly, but the actual PDFs all include pages from the first one onwards but the actual size of the chunks goes up by 5 pages per iteration. So, instead of splitting into the first 5 pages, the next 5 pages and so on, the first PDF is a 5 page document starting on page 1, the second a 10 page document starting on page 1, etc.

Here's the code. My election update-addled brain can't figure out the flaw at the moment.

Appreciate the help!

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
pdf = PdfFileReader(path,'rb')
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
p = 0
end = pdf.getNumPages()
while p < end:
    try:
        for page in range(p,p+5):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
        output_filename = '{}_pages_{}_to_{}.pdf'.format(fname, p,p+5)
        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)
        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
        p += 5
    except:
        for page in range(p,end):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
        output_filename = '{}_pages_{}_to_{}.pdf'.format(fname, p,end)
        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)
        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
        p += 5
```

####### EDIT #########
Answered by Random Davis. The PdfFileWriter() needed to be reset with every iteration. Here's the updated version:

```
fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
pdf = PdfFileReader(path,'rb')
p = 0
step = 5
end = pdf.getNumPages()
while p < end:
    try:
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        for page in range(p,p+step):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
        output_filename = '{}_pages_{}_to_{}.pdf'.format(fname, p+1,p+step)
        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)
        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
        p += step
    except:
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        for page in range(p,end):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
        output_filename = '{}_pages_{}_to_{}.pdf'.format(fname, p+1,end)
        with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
            pdf_writer.write(out)
        print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
        p += step
```

Comment: You define `pdf_writer` just once before your loop, then call `pdf_writer.addPage()` multiple times while never resetting `pdf_writer`. So, of course it's just going to keep filling up with more and more pages. You should probably have `pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()` be running after every time you write out a new file, or at the top of your loop.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks for that! I should have looked into how exactly that class works. Appreciate the correction.

Comment: No problem. Although full disclosure, I didn't look up the class or do any research. Just, logically, that's what you're doing in the code, and given what you're experiencing, I guessed that the object wasn't getting the pages cleared out of it each time it was written.